# Inner join a table on 2 primary key columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two table with 2 primary keys on id and group_id

```
id      group_id      name
01       333           Ken
05       123           Tom
03       231           Mary
05       94            Brandy
.... more rows

id      group_id      name
05       123           Tom
03       231           Mary
05       94            Brandy
07       384           Jane
.... more rows
```

expected multilevel dataframe

```
        df1    df2          df1    df2 
         group_id             name
id      
05       123   123         Tom     Tom
03       231   231        Mary     Mary
05       94    94        Brandy    Brandy
```

I want to merge 2 tables with inner join on the primary key columns (id and group_id), but so far I can only do it for one column and it's complaining Shape of passed values is (5, 3012), indices imply (5, 2915) because I have duplicate ids.

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('id'), df2.set_index('id')], axis='columns', keys=['df1', 'df2'],join='inner')
```

Comment: did you try `merge`? `pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner',on=['id','group_id'])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i want a multiindex dataframe

Comment: `pd.concat([d.set_index(['id','group_id']) for d in (df1,df2)], 
          axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2'])`?

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
newdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on=['id,'group_id'], right_on=['id','group_id])
```